# jQuery toggle disabled click on link

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, click, toggle

how do I enable a toggle function on a table row, while still maintaining the ability to click through to the page specified in a link? The link is within the td, like `table tr td a`.

The HTML for the row looks like this:

```
<tr class="listitem">
 <td>
   <a href="/apartments/4df632fd35be357701000005">E 64th St, Manhattan, NY 10065, USA</a>
 </td>
 ...
</tr>
```

And so far the JavaScript I am using is something like this:

```
$('.listitem').toggle(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

Which is disabling the ability to click on the `<a>` element. How do I get around this?

Comment: What are you trying to do on toggle?

Answer (score 1):

`toggle()` function does not disable the ability to click, as I know. Or, show me the example with http://jsfiddle.net/, please.

And you are using `toggle()` function in a wrong way. You can't pass two function arguments to `toggle()` function. Check this documentation: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

what about `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly what you want, you should be able to register a different callback for the anchors, much the same way you defined them for the tablerows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you're doing in the toggle functions that's preventing the link from working, but one thing you could try is to prevent event propagation to the tr when the link is clicked on:

```
$('tr a').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You given two parameters two `toggle()`, which both are `function()`s, but as much i know `toggle()` takes `duration` as 1st parameter and `callback` as second parameter. Please check this.